# How to include a component in all vue-routes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In a SPA, I have made a header component which changes slightly on each page.

```
export default {
  name: 'header',
  //add some stuff based on user data
  data: function (router) {
    return {
      //some data      
    }
  },   
}
```

And here are my routes:

```
export default [
  {path:'/', component: showJokesAll },
  {path:'/hot', component: showJokesHotAll },
  {path:'/add', component: addJoke  }  ,
  {path: '/login', component: webLogin},
  {path: '/profile', component: webProfile},
  {path: '/auth', component: webProfile},

]
```

I'm wondering what is the correct way to inject the `header` component into all routes?

**Update**: When I try to import the header component into app's `main.js`:

```
import Header from './components/header.vue'

Vue.component('page-header', Header);
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

Comment: Just declare it globally: `Vue.component('page-header', Header)`

Comment: Do you mean in `main.js`?

Comment: Yes, if that's where you are importing Vue and creating your main Vue instance. Usually though, I just declare the components I'm using in each components `component` property rather than registering them globally, because it makes it clearer when reading back you code where each component comes from.

Comment: @craig_h Please refer to my updated question. How can I import the component into the main.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same header component in all routes. place it before `router-view` and change your css layout.
If you wan't to change the content of the header component depending on each route. You can place another `<router-view name="header">` inside your header component. And then in your array of routes

```
 <template> 
        <div> 
          <app-header><../>
          <router-view><../>
        </div> 
    </template>
```

Otherwise:

```
export default [
  {
     path:'/', 
     components: {
       default: defaultComponentForThisRoute,
       header: yourRouteHeaderComponent,
     } 
  },


]
```

Comment: I tried placing `'app-header': Header,` into `App.js` components and then added `<app-header></app-header>` above `<router-view></router-view>` as you suggested, but then vue.js complains that `Component template should contain exactly one root element`

Comment: yes because your template looks like this
`<template>
    <app-header><../>
    <router-view><../>
</template>`
Instead of
`<template>
    <div>
    <app-header><../>
    <router-view><../>
   </div>
</template>`

Comment: every template should have exactly ONE DIRECT CHILD element

Comment: Right, That's what I was looking for. So please complete answer and I'll accept. Thanks!